# Trying to post a form via ajax with CURL, JSON and webservice calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, curl

Hi i have been trying to post fields to a Web Services provided by a client. 
the client gave me specific document etc to use has exemple.

im new to webservices but i bet im close ... to results here is what the client 
wants me to send.

Here are some examples/documentation using cURL:

```
$ curl --data '{"firstname": "William S.", "lastname": "Walker", "language": "EN", "city": "Ottawa", "state": "ON", "country": "CA", "telephone": "613-737-5719", "mobilephone": "613-737-5719", "fax": "613-737-5719", "email": "WilliamSWalker@rhyta.com", "entreprise": "Helping Hand", "passtype": "None", "passwordchanged": false, "professionalactivity": "Respiratory care practitioner", "registrationdate": "2010-04-20T20:08:21", "sectorofinterest": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis nisl vestibulum, egestas enim vel, egestas erat. Aenean sodales ipsum tortor, ut facilisis elit fermentum eget.", "webpage": "http://www.GolfCleaners.com", "workplace": "Helping Hand"}' -X POST -H 'Authorization: Token token="token"' https://link.mobile.test.com/api/v1/conferences/4/participants
```

im trying to send using ajax and post to this function. 
here is my ajax

function addAttendee(){

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://link.mobile.test.com/api/v1/conferences/4/participants",
    type: "POST",

    dataType: "html",
    data: "firstname=Kevin&lastname=Gauthier&telephone=4502605353&email=kevin@konige.com&token=7f5cebd3b6c62559f53d1179571e10da",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        // handle your successful response here
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        // handle your fail response here
    }
});
}
```

What i dont understand is that this will return that **HTTP Token: Access denied.**
can someone help im a very confused at the moment.

maybe it's just me and i don't understand the concept of a web service.

thanks in advance

Comment: does anyone have knowledge on how to post form using webservices? all i have acording to the company is post to the url add the conference_ID and TOKEN... but im lost i tryed this and with no success

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample AJAX call that i just used today to POST data in Jquery.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/feedbacks.json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ category: "categoryType", message_text: "messageString", anonymous: "anonymous_user" ,other_information: "otherInfo", browser_name: "browser_info", ssm_version: "ssmVersion"}),
        success: function () {
            window.close();
        },
        error: function(model, response) {
            var errMsg = "Your feedback could not be submitted."
            window.appEvents.trigger(UIEvents.app.failure, errMsg, 'modal')
        }
    });
```

Comment: in my case where would this token go ?